# Get message and use it Telegram bot (pyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am making a Telegram bot. I want write code that:
user send command - /color
bot ask ‘Red: ‘
user send text

How can I get that message without ‘/’ ?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['color'])
def info_produkts(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Red: ")
    text = Update.message.replay_text()
```

But it's not working...
I am working in visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

use regexp= keyboard like that

```
`@bot.message_handler(regexp='color')
```